# Update data in database Firestore through TextFormField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**How to make the data that is written in the TextFormField update the data that has already been recorded**

*here is my login screen. This is part of the registration page. the same code on the login page*

```
String _email, _password, id;
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final db = Firestore.instance;

Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          autofocus: false,
                          // controller: _email,
                          // validator: Validator.validateEmail,
                          onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'Enter your email',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'SIGN UP',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(),
                              ),
                              Transform.translate(
                                offset: Offset(10.0, 0.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                  child: FlatButton(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: 
                                       BorderRadius.circular(28.0)
                                    ),
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      // _emailSignUp(
                                      //   email:_email.text,
                                      //   password:_password.text,
                                      //   context: context
                                      // );

                                      createData();
                                      signUp();
                                      sharedPreferences = await 
                     SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                     sharedPreferences.setString("email", _email);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
 void createData() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      DocumentReference ref = await db.collection('users').add({'email': '$_email', 'name': 'UserName', 'userPhotoURL': 'url'});
      setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
      print(ref.documentID);
    }
  }
```

**AccountScreen.**
*Here I want to update the data users through TextFormField. I want to determine what data needs to be changed depending on the user who came in*

```
class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AccountScreenState();
}

class AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String countries;
  String selected;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  String _name, _email;
  final db = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataPreference();
  }

  getDataPreference() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _email = sharedPreferences.getString("email");
    });
  }

  // void updateData(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
  //   await db.collection('users').document(doc.documentID).updateData({'email': '$_email', 'name': '$_name'});
  //   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home_screen');
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Your account"), backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
      body: 
      Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        child: Form(
          key:_formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            AccountImage(),
            ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
                title: TextFormField(
                  onSaved: (input) => _name = input,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      hintText: "Name",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                )),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white),
              title: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: "Email",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                initialValue: _email,
                onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.language, color: Colors.white),
              title: DropDownCountries(),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.blue[700],
                elevation: 3.0,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  height: 45.0,
                  child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // updateData();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home_screen');
                  }
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `update` the record like this you can get `documentID` from document

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(userID)// use documentID here to update particular document
        .updateData({
      "email": emailController.text,//This is the data i.e going to be updated
      "City": cityController.text,//This is the data i.e going to be updated
      "Phone": phoneNumberController.text.toString(),//This is the data i.e going to be updated
});
```

Comment: And userID is that? And how will it determine what data needs to be updated?

Comment: It(userID) define which user's document(data) should be updated with new values. The data that has to be updated will be written in set. Example I wrote displayName...

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. Can you also write code that writes data to the database for your code, or is my code suitable for writing?

Comment: the code in your question is for adding new document with data. Once  you got document Id, use it to specify the document which data has to be updated. Bdw, if got your answer, please accept it, else comment your doubt.

Comment: The document ID in my code is ref.documentID, right?

Comment: now in your code instead of userID I have to write ref.documentID ?

Comment: yes,and change data with your data... if you can add more code of what you are trying to do  it would be easier for me to answer

Comment: I have a login screen through which the user is registered - the data is written to the database. Then when the user logged in, he has a screen account page where he can change his mail, name ... How to make it determine what data needs to be changed if I have for example 5 users in the database?

Comment: upload your account page code I'll see how its working then I'll answer you properly. Because your fetching user details and showing them in textfield or just buttons that's why.

Comment: as you saved email in shared preferences also save user documentId while creating account.. then in account page on save button press use my answer code with document Id you saved in shared preference instead of userID

Comment: I apologize, but can not write how I save user documentID. I tried I can not understand how

Comment: In loginpage you are using createData() method. right. In that instead of printing add documentId to shared preference.

Comment: Have you stored document id in shared preference?? if yes, use the answer save by saving document in userID string

Comment: no problem, if your query cleared feel free to accept answer.

Comment: You can look at the error, you can know how to solve
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962845/flutter-firestore-error-with-bloc-pattern